# How to resolve ambigiously named extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, ambiguous-call

I have a DataTable that I'm trying to enumerate over with the AsEnumerable extension method on  System.Linq.Enumerable.  The problem is that there is an identically named extension method on System.Data.DataTableExtensions.  I need to use both namespaces in my class so removing one of the using statements is not an option.

How do I declare that I want the AsEnumerable method from System.Linq.Enumerable and not the System.Data.DataTableExtensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just static methods so you could do this:

```
DataTable dt;
System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable(dt);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept that as the answer. I was hoping there was a way to still use the extension method though.

Answer (score 4):

DataTable does not implement IEnumerable<T>, or even IEnumerable, so you cannot call `Enumerable.AsEnumerable()` on it directly.  That is what `DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()` is for in the first place.

Comment: I think you are right.  For some reason VS was giving me the ambiguous error for that method which prompted the question, and now I can't recreate it.  I accidentally voted you down, if you edit your answer I'll vote you back up.